# save button code using c# ado.net disconnected architecture

Tags: c#-4.0

Error: The name 'dealerdetailTableAdapter' does not exist in the current context

```
   private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t = kalliskaBillingDataSet.Tables["DealerDetail"];
        r = t.NewRow();
        r[0] = txtdealerID.Text;
        r[1] = txtname.Text;
        r[2] = txtaddress.Text;
        r[3] = txtphoneno.Text;
        t.Rows.Add(r);
        //'dealerdetailTableAdapter' does not exist in the current context.
        dealerdetailTableAdapter.Update(kalliskaBillingDataSet);
        txtdealerID.Text = System.Convert.ToString(r[0]);
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved", "DealerDetail", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
```